# SqlAlchemy error when formatting a long in psql query

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two classes somewhat like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger

class State(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'state'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False, index=True)

class Person(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'person'
   id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
   state_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

And then I'm trying to execute a query like this against our Postgres 9.2 database:

```
tennessee = Session.query(
   State
).filter(
    State.name == "TN"
).first()

query = select(
    [Person.id]
).where(
    Person.state_id == tennessee.id
)

person = Session.execute(query).first()
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
syntax error at or near "L"
WHERE person.state_id = 599485L...
                              ^
```

I can fix it by casting `state.id` to an `int`, but that feels dangerous given that the type in the database is `BIGINT`. Why would sqlalchemy leave the `L` on the end of the long when it generates the query? I am using sqlalchemy 0.8.2

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Also, is there any reason you're using such an old version of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Python 2.7 - and we're in the process of updating our version of SQLAlchemy, but we're not done yet :(

Comment: I copied your code and installed SQLAlchemy 0.8.2 but couldn't reproduce the error. It looks like the `L` is only added when a long is `repr()`d. If you print a long or `str()` it, it won't have the `L`. Are you using an older version of `psycopg2`?

Comment: We're using `psycopg2` version `2.5.2`. It's not as terribly out-of-date as SQLAlchemy, but it is a little old. I am able to reproduce using: `select([Person.id]).where(Person.id == 5L).compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})`

Comment: I get an unrelated error when I try to run that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm not seeing the error in the latest version of SQLAlchemy, so I'll probably just cast to an `int` for now, and focus my efforts on getting our SQLAlchemy upgraded.